# Postresql: Composite types and select into

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, composite-types

Can somebody explain this? (evrything is in the example below!). I use postgresql 9.4.
WARNING! In the code below I drop the "object type" composite type and the "example_data" temporary table , be sure you don't have these in your database... Just in case, I commented the drop commands, uncomment them if needed...

```
--drop type if exists object_type;
--drop table if exists example_data;

create type object_type as (
       id text
       ,value text);

create temporary table example_data as (
       select
            'id1'::text as id,
            'example value'::text as value);

do $$
declare
    my_object object_type;
begin

    -- The fiolowing doesn't work, we can't use INTO with the whole object
    -- Some how, it tries to put the whole object into the first attribute:
    select (id,value)::object_type
    into my_object
    from example_data;

    raise warning 'ID: %, VALUE: %', my_object.id, my_object.value;

    -- What a shame! It would have been so much more convenient than the following:    
    -- to feed the object we need to repeat each one of the attribute in the INTO section:
    select id, value
    into  my_object.id, my_object.value
    from example_data;

    raise warning 'ID: %, VALUE: %', my_object.id, my_object.value;

/*
In that example it is not so bad, but when you have very large object, it is very ugly to repeat each one
of the attribute, for example:
select  (att1, att2, att3, att4, att5, att6, att7, att8, att9, att10)::object_type2 into my_object2

and, (very heavy):
select  att1, att2, att3, att4, att5, att6, att7, att8, att9, att10
into my_object2.att1, my_object2.att2, my_object2.att3, my_object2.att4, my_object2.att5, my_object2.att6,
     my_object2.att7, my_object2.att8, my_object2.att9, my_object2.att10

*/

end $$;

--drop type if exists object_type;
--drop table if exists example_data;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW)

```
...
select id, value
into my_object
from example_data;
...
```